# MySQL database orginization and PHP select

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, select

I am setting up a MySQL database and will be querying it with PHP.  Is is better to break the information up into multiple tables and do select queries on each of the tables; or is it better to put all the items in one table and do a single select query?

For example:

It will hold information on upto 7 cars; which would mean that their will be approximately 50 columns or so.

```
Table_design 1
----------------------
table_all
    username
    car1_make
    car1_model
    car1_year
    car1_condition
    car1_tires
    car1_color
    car2_make
    car2_model
    car2_year
    car2_condition
    car2_tires
    car2_color
----------------------

Table_design 2
----------------------
table_1
    username
    car1_make
    car1_model
    car1_year
    car1_condition
    car1_tires
    car1_color

table_2
    username
    car2_make
    car2_model
    car2_year
    car2_condition
    car2_tires
    car2_color
----------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three tables. This way you're not limited to the amount of information you can add to a car. And you're not limited to the number of cars a user can have access to.

If you ever need a spreadsheet of users, query the `users` table. If you ever need an inventory of cars, query the `cars` table. If you ever need to know which cars each users are associated with, query the `userscars`.

See [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

- users

  - User ID
  - User First Name
  - User Last Name
- cars

  - Car ID
  - Car Make
  - Car Model
- usercars

  - User ID
  - Car ID

Comment: I don't like the surrogate PK usage here since Make/Model information is fairly static. If you are stuck on it, I would at least UNIQUE the Make + Model (which is the true PK) to prevent more than one "car" entry of the same Make+Model from being entered. This way the table contents will actually get reused rather than duplicated. I would also add a YEAR column to the car table and include it in the make+model UK.

Answer (score 1):

What Jonathan said, though his table structure is many-to-many, this isn't neccesary unless multiple people might own the same car.

```
* users
      o User ID
      o User First Name
      o User Last Name
* cars
      o Car ID
      o User ID
      o Car Make
      o Car Model
```

makes more sense, and is easier to query.

Comment: Except that the cars table isn't truely a unique car. It's actually just storing a surrogate for the true PK of "Make and Model". So it is very likely that a single user might have multiple cars of the same make+model.